# Trouble joining the tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to join two tables but there is a problem with it.
No error pops up but the columns of the table after joining are not showing up.
This is the query I have made in order to find the date difference and then join the table with another one.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(Select job_empl_job.*,(job_empl_job.emplj_lastdate -trunc(sysdate)) 
AS 
difference from job_empl_job 
INNER JOIN 
job_city 
ON
job_city.city_id=job_empl_job.emplj_city)
WHERE difference < 16 AND difference > 0
```

Comment: Just a note of explanation as to why you're not seeing the columns you're expecting to see... it's because you haven't added them into the select list. Do that, and you should be fine (e.g. `select job_empl_job.*, job_city.*, ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT   a.* , b.* , 
(SELECT trunc(EMPLJ_LASTDATE - sysdate ) from dual )as days 
FROM 
job_empl_job a  
INNER JOIN 
JOB_CITY b 
ON 
a.EMPLJ_CITY=b.CITY_ID 
)
WHERE
days < 16 and days > 0
```

Comment: I highly appreciate fa06 for his help but I have approved the solution that is working for me and not based on anyone's opinion.

Comment: @JahanzebAwan  You don't need the scalar subquery to do the date difference; I'm not sure why you have added it in?

Comment: alias works after where query in oracle, without scalar subquery 'days' will not be recognized

Answer (score 3):

You can try below

```
Select job_empl_job.*,trunc(sysdate)-TO_date(job_empl_job.emplj_lastdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS difference 
from job_empl_job INNER JOIN job_city 
ON
job_city.city_id=job_empl_job.emplj_city
WHERE trunc(sysdate)-TO_date(job_empl_job.emplj_lastdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy')> 0  and trunc(sysdate)-TO_date(job_empl_job.emplj_lastdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') < 16
```

Comment: This join should be correct job_city.city_id=job_empl_job.emplj_city is it correct? is is on the primary key and foreign key?

Comment: @AliTahir, then it would be great if you provide some sample data

Comment: @fa06 thank you for your help. I have found the solution but I highly appreciate your effort.